# Javascript Conditional Statement Not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I see to be having issues using this Javascript code to make a list of download options appear and disappear accordingly based on their visibility when triggered: If it's visible, it will be hidden. If it's hidden, it will be visible.

```
window.openList = function(listName) {
    var list = document.getElementById(listName + "-list");
    if (list.style.visibility == "hidden") {
        list.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else if (list.style.visibility == "visible") {
        list.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Here's the html that will be interacting with the Javascript:

```
<div id="downloads">
                <div id="redtech-gpu-download" class="downloads">
                    <p onclick="javascript: openList('redtech-gpu-download');">Redtech GPU</p>
                    <div id="redtech-gpu-download-list" class="download-list">
                        <span class="download-list-item download-list-item-a">
                            <p onclick="javascript: window.open('files/redtech-gpu-001.zip', '_blank');">GPU Ver 0.0.1 Alpha</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="download-list-item download-list-item-b">
                            <p>{ More Coming Soon! }</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="redtech-memory-download" class="downloads">
                    <p onclick="javascript: openList('redtech-memory-download');">Redtech Memory</p>
                    <div id="redtech-memory-download-list" class="download-list">
                        <!--<span class="download-list-item download-list-item-a">
                            <p onclick="javascript: window.open('files/redtech-memory-001.zip', '_blank');">Memory Ver 0.0.1 Alpha</p>
                        </span>-->
                        <span class="download-list-item download-list-item-b">
                            <p>{ Coming Soon! }</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I assume you're setting the `visibility` in your CSS? `style.visibility` will only work for inline styles. You should use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to read the computed CSS styles

Comment: I'm using inline-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you provided, `list.style.visibility` is not set before you attempt to check it. Thus its value is going to be `""`, which is neither equal to `"visible"` or `"hidden"`.

There are two possible quick fixes to your code you can make to fix this: Either include `style="visibility:visible;"` on the tags you plan on being able to hide, or make your `else if` statement just an `else` statement (no if).

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is not correct. This is what you actually do:

```
if (something) {
   //do something
} 

else if (list.style.visibility == "visible") {
    //if the if case is false do this:
}
```

but here after normally would be an else clause, what to do if nothing matches the above statements.

The correct way would be:

```js
window.openList = function(listName) {
    var list = document.getElementById(listName + "-list");
    console.log(list);
    if (list.style.visibility == "hidden") {
        list.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        list.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="downloads">
                <div id="redtech-gpu-download" class="downloads">
                    <p onclick="openList('redtech-gpu-download');">Redtech GPU</p>
                    <div id="redtech-gpu-download-list" class="download-list">
                        <span class="download-list-item download-list-item-a">
                            <p onclick="javascript: window.open('files/redtech-gpu-001.zip', '_blank');">GPU Ver 0.0.1 Alpha</p>
                        </span>
                        <span class="download-list-item download-list-item-b">
                            <p>More Coming Soon!</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="redtech-memory-download" class="downloads">
                    <p onclick="javascript: openList('redtech-memory-download');">Redtech Memory</p>
                    <div id="redtech-memory-download-list" class="download-list">
                        <!--<span class="download-list-item download-list-item-a">
                            <p onclick="javascript: window.open('files/redtech-memory-001.zip', '_blank');">Memory Ver 0.0.1 Alpha</p>
                        </span>-->
                        <span class="download-list-item download-list-item-b">                          <p> Coming Soon!</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why would there be a clause?

Comment: The same issue occurs: It just dosen't want to work.